# Scheduling a Python Script to Manipulate .txt File in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cron, schedule

I'd like to have a Python script executed every 30 minutes all day long.

The inputFile.txt file:

```
Forecast

Today's high: 45 degrees
```

The convert.py file code is:

```
# Conversion code

# Open and read the file after the appending:
resultFile = open("output.html", "w")

# Open the Template file
with open('inputFile.txt') as templateFile:
    templateCode = templateFile.readlines()

resultFile.write('<h1>')    
resultFile.write(templateCode[0])
resultFile.write('</h1>')
resultFile.write('\n')
resultFile.write('\n')
resultFile.write('<p>') 
resultFile.write(templateCode[2]) 
resultFile.write('</p>')


# Close the Result File
resultFile.close()
templateFile.close()
```

The output.html file after running:

```html
<h1>Forecast
</h1>

<p>Today's high: 45 degrees
</p>
```

The code can run on a Cloud Shell on the Google Cloud Platform, and I can get a Cron job to execute if the files are on my computer.

My question is how can I get this to work in the Google Cloud Platform?

I've been researching Google Cloud Scheduler, Google Functions, Google Cloud Run, Google Cloud Storage, etc. but I can't seem to get it all to connect in the way a Cron job would work on a server.

Note: This is my first question here and I'm new to development. Wish me luck!